# POSIX parent/child threads not sharing data

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

One final question for the evening. I have a homework question that I cannot seem to solve, and after spending the better part of the night on it, I'll ask it here.

The problem is a program that is to calculate the Fibonacci sequence given an integer input at the command line (./foo.out 15, for example, and it will calculate the first 15 Fibonacci numbers). The additional parameters are as follows:

1.) It must use two POSIX threads, a parent thread and a child thread.
2.) It must share data (an array) between them.

Currently, the function is breaking when program control passes back to the parent thread. All I am getting is a completely non-descriptive segfault. As can be seen below, I have it outputting at every possible change in control.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *fibonacci(void *param, int numbers[]);
void *runner(void *param);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_attr_t attr;


  if ( argc != 2)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: 426.out <integer value> \n");
      return -1;
    }

  if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Argument must be non-negative\n");
      return -2;
    }

      pthread_attr_init(&attr);
      pthread_create(&tid, &attr, runner, argv[1]);
      pthread_join(tid,NULL);

  return 0;
}

void *fibonacci(void *param, int numbers[])
    {
      int it, IT_MAX;

      printf("Entering Child Thread:\n");

      IT_MAX = atoi(param);
      numbers[0] = 0;
      numbers[1] = 1;

      for (it = 2; it < IT_MAX; ++it)
    {
      numbers[it] = (numbers[it - 1] + numbers[it - 2]);
    }
      for (it = 0; it < IT_MAX; ++it)
    {
      printf("%d\n", numbers[it]);
    }

      printf("Exiting Child Function.\n");
    }

  void *runner(void *param)
  {
    int it, IT_MAX;
    int numbers[IT_MAX];

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    printf("Entering Parent Thread:\n");


    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_create(&tid, &attr, fibonacci(param, numbers), NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    IT_MAX = atoi(param);    

    for (it = 0; it < IT_MAX; it++)
      {
    printf("%d\n", numbers[it]); // I suspect the program breaks here
                                   // It produces a segfault rather than this
      }

    printf("Leaving Parent Thread\n");
  }
```

The question I have, if it is not clear from above, is what am I doing wrong. I am using gcc, and have been using the `-Wall` `-Werror` and `-lpthread`. `-Werror` keeps throwing "Control Structure going to end of non-void function", but nothing has anything to say about what can be causing the segfault. As before, I looked for the last hour for a question or article that addresses this, so if this is a dupe, please point me to the question or article in which it is addressed. Thanks to anyone in advance for their help.

Answer (score 3):

One of your problems is in this line:

```
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, fibonacci(param, numbers), NULL);
```

Instead of starting a thread with the `fibonacci()` function, this *calls* the `fibbonacci()` function in the current thread and passes the result to `pthread_create()` as the thread start function.  `fibonacci()` doesn't return a function pointer, so this new thread will crash the program.

You need to just pass `fibonacci` as the third parameter.

Futhermore, `fibonacci()` must be declared as `void *fibonacci(void *)` in order to be used as a thread start function.  If you want to pass two parameters, you'll need to place them into a `struct` and pass a pointer to that.

This pair of lines is also problematic:

```
int it, IT_MAX;
int numbers[IT_MAX];
```

`IT_MAX` is an uninitialised variable, and you use it here to define the size of the `numbers[]` array.  That could also be leading to your crash.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, fibonacci(param, numbers), NULL);
```

does not pass the address of `fibonacci()` to `pthread_create()` but calls `fibonacci(param, numbers)`and passes the result returned to `pthread_create()` as 3rd argument.